# MAP KIT white on storyboard

Tags: ios, mapkit

My mapkit is not showing in my storyboard but it does show active not sure why is not showing gray like before. Please find screenshot for the same 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDhFU.png).

Comment: Have you confirmed delegates etc.?

Comment: Can you share your code? Is Mapkit added programmatically in viewcontroller?

Comment: i have confirm delegates even using a new project and adding the mapkit it shows invisible in my story board